# Dynamic Binding to C# Events Using Reflection

Tags: c#, events

I have a WPF control with very poor documentation.

In the codebehind I'd like to reflect over the events that the control fires using `GetType().GetEVents()` and add a handler to each one which simply prints out the name of the event.

This would allow me to see what interacting with the control is actually doing.

So far I have:

```
foreach (var e in GetType().GetEvents())
{
    var name = e.Name;
    var handler = new Action<object,object>( (o1,o2) =>Console.WriteLine(name));

    try
    {
        e.AddEventHandler(
                     this,
                     Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                               e.EventHandlerType,
                               handler.Target, 
                               handler.Method
                               ));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Failed to bind to event {0}", e.Name);
    }
}
```

Which seems to work when the event signature is `(object,EventArgs)` but fails to bind when on certain other events.

Is there a way to do this without necessarily knowing the signature of the event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` class to generate dynamic handlers matching the signature of the event - into which you simply place a call to `Console.WriteLine`.

The [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350515.aspx) method (have provided a link to the specific overload you'd need) can be used to generate a `Func<>` or, more likely, `Action<>` of the correct type.

You reflect the delegate type of the event (grabbing it's `Invoke` method as mentioned by @Davio) to pull out all the arguments and create `ParameterExpression`s for each of those to supply to the lambda method.

Here's a complete solution that you can paste into a standard unit test, I'll explain afterwards in a follow-up edit:

```
public class TestWithEvents
{
  //just using random delegate signatures here
  public event Action Handler1;
  public event Action<int, string> Handler2;

  public void RaiseEvents(){
    if(Handler1 != null)
        Handler1();
    if(Handler2 != null)
      Handler2(0, "hello world");
  }
}

public static class DynamicEventBinder
{
  public static Delegate GetHandler(System.Reflection.EventInfo ev) {
    string name = ev.Name;
    // create an array of ParameterExpressions
    // to pass to the Expression.Lambda method so we generate
    // a handler method with the correct signature.
    var parameters = ev.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().
      Select((p, i) => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, "p" + i)).ToArray();

    // this and the Compile() can be turned into a one-liner, I'm just
    // splitting it here so you can see the lambda code in the Console
    // Note that we use the Event's type for the lambda, so it's tightly bound
    // to that event.
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(ev.EventHandlerType,
      Expression.Call(typeof(Console).GetMethod(
        "WriteLine",
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
        null,
        new[] { typeof(string) },
        null), Expression.Constant(name + " was fired!")), parameters);

    //spit the lambda out (for bragging rights)
    Console.WriteLine(
      "Compiling dynamic lambda {0} for event \"{1}\"", lambda, name);
    return lambda.Compile();
  }

  //note - an unsubscribe might be handy - which would mean
  //caching all the events that were subscribed for this object
  //and the handler.  Probably makes more sense to turn this type
  //into an instance type that binds to a single object...
  public static void SubscribeAllEvents(object o){
    foreach(var e in o.GetType().GetEvents())
    {
      e.AddEventHandler(o, GetHandler(e));
    }
  }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSubscribe()
{
  TestWithEvents testObj = new TestWithEvents();
  DynamicEventBinder.SubscribeAllEvents(testObj);
  Console.WriteLine("Raising events...");
  testObj.RaiseEvents();
  //check the console output
}
```

An outline - we start with a type that has some events (I'm using `Action` but it should work with anything), and has a method that we can use to test-fire all those events that have subscribers.

then to the `DynamicEventBinder` class, which has two methods: `GetHandler` - to get a handler for a particular event for a particular type; and `SubscribeAllEvents` which binds all those events for a given instance of that type - which simply loops over all the events, calling `AddEventHandler` for each, calling `GetHandler` to get the handler.

The `GetHandler` method is where the meat and bones is - and does exactly as I suggest in the outline.

A delegate type has an `Invoke` member compiled into it by the compiler which mirrors the signature of any handler that it can be bound to.  So, we reflect that method and get any parameters it has, creating Linq `ParameterExpression` instances for each.  Naming the parameter is a nicety, it's the type here that matters.

Then we build a single-line lambda, whose body is basically:

```
 Console.WriteLine("[event_name] was fired!");
```

*(Note here that the event's name is pulled into the dynamic code and incorporated into a constant string as far as the code is concerned)*

When we build the lambda, we also tell the `Expression.Lambda` method the type of delegate we intend to build (bound directly to the delegate type of the event), and by passing the `ParameterExpression` array that we created before, it will generate a method which has that many parameters.  We use the `Compile` method to actually compile the dynamic code, which gives us a `Delegate` which we can then use as an argument to `AddEventHandler`.

I sincerely hope this explains what we've done - if you've not worked with Expressions and dynamic code before it can be mind-bending stuff.  Indeed, some of the people I work with simply call this voodoo.

Comment: This sounds interesting but i'm struggling to implement!

Comment: I'll put together a test with type + and event for you to use... might take half an hour...

Comment: I've got to the part where I call AddHandler on the EventInfo object and I'm getting: *"Object of type 'System.Action`2[System.Object,System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'."*

Comment: Perfect! I was almost there but I wasn't passing the event handler type into the Expression.Lambda function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx

They use the delegate's Invoke-method to get the signature.